# Using GPL code with MPL code

Tags: licensing, gpl, mpl

I've done a spot of Googling, and all I can find is information on using code under the MPL in a larger GPL licensed project.
What I really want to know is: can I included GPL(v3) licensed code(/binaries) in a larger MPL(2.0) licensed project?

My understanding so far is that I can't, and that any project which uses GPL software must also be released under the GPL. Is this correct?

If this is correct, can I write software and release it under the MPL, even if it depends on a GPL library, as long as I don't distribute the GPL licensed parts with my MPL licensed parts?

And, if I then want to distribute both parts as a "larger work", how would the overarching GPL affect my MPL code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disclaimer, this is similar to my [other answer on MIT & GPL](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/204497/53019), but there are some nuances involved with MPL.

> can I included GPL(v3) licensed code(/binaries) in a larger MPL(2.0) licensed project?

**Short answer:** No, you can't*.  They'll become subject to the copyleft.

<sub>* See the longer answer as this is one of the trickier ones</sub>

**Long answer:**

*Reference 1* ) The [Wikipedia article on license compatibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/License_compatibility) has a good section on [GPL compatibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/License_compatibility#GPL_compatibility):

> Many of the most common free software licenses, such as the original MIT/X license, ... are "GPL-compatible". That is, their code can be combined with a program under the GPL without conflict (*the new combination would have the GPL applied to the whole*).

[emphasis added]

*Reference 2* ) And more explicitly from the [FSF FAQ on GPL compatibility](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#WhatDoesCompatMean):

> It means that the other license and the GNU GPL are compatible; you can combine code released under the other license with code released under the GNU GPL in one larger program.

And just for edification, here's the [FSF's comments on various licenses](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html)

FSF has a number of comments on the [MPL license](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#MPL-2.0).

Short version is that your combined work must be released as GPL.

**Where it gets tricky**

Let's say we have project `Foo` licensed under MPL, and project `Bar` licensed under GPL and which wants to use `Foo`.

`Bar+Foo` is allowed since the licenses are compatible, and the release of `Bar+Foo` must be GPL as `Bar` is GPL.  `Foo`, by itself and without `Bar` *or* `Bar+Foo`, is still available under the MPL license.  Said another way, `Bar+Foo` has no license impact upon `Foo` itself.

The resulting license of the project combination is a forward acting event for the combination only.  It is *not* a retroactive event.  MPL takes this a step further with section 3.3 and explicitly requires the owner of `Bar+Foo` to provide `Foo`'s distribution in MPL form.

So if someone else wants to take `Foo` and do something else with it, they are still free to do so without the copyleft provision of the GPL.  However, if they take `Bar+Foo`, delete `Bar` and only use `+Foo` then they are still bound by the terms of the GPL since `Bar+Foo` was GPL'd.

In my opinion, this is about as close as a license can get to nullifying the viral effect of GPL. The owners of `Foo` are making sure that it continues to live and be advertised as MPL while still letting you do what you want with your GPL'd application.

**You also asked:**

> If this is correct, can I write software and release it under the MPL, even if it depends on a GPL library, as long as I don't distribute the GPL licensed parts with my MPL licensed parts?

No, this is not correct.  It will be GPL since it depends upon a GPL library.

> And, if I then want to distribute both parts as a "larger work", how would the overarching GPL affect my MPL code?

You'll distribute the broader work as GPL.
You'll also need to provide the smaller MPL work as MPL.

Comment: OK, that seems to make sense. Essentially, I have to GPL it one way or another, even if I keep it MPL too, and the parts which _depend_ on the GPL'd library can't be MPL. Correct?

Comment: @AngusIreland The combined application (GPL bits + MPL bits) must be GPL due to the copyleft.  The MPL bits must* remain MPL outside of the combined application.  The * is because you own the MPL bits and are therefore free to relicense.  Relative "size" of the code doesn't matter.  One little bitty GPL lib injects the copyleft to the entire application.